# I can't run all my test cases correctly, what's wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, return

Complete the *divisibleSumPairs* function in the editor below. It should return the integer count of pairs meeting the criteria.

*divisibleSumPairs* has the following parameter(s):

- *n*: the integer length of array *ar*
- *ar*: an array of integers
- *k*: the integer to divide the pair sum by

Print the number of *(i, j)* pairs where *i < j* and *ar[i] + ar[j]* is evenly divisible by *k*.

I don't know what is wrong, only some cases has worked

```
  static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, int[] ar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if ((ar[i]<ar[j]) && ((ar[i]+ar[j])%k)== 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
        return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please proof-read your questions in the future before submitting them. Part of your text was omitted because of a less-than sign (<) being confused with an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you check for *ar[i] < ar[j]* while the problem statement says *i < j*:

```
static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, int[] ar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (i < j && (ar[i] + ar[j]) % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The algorithm can be further optimized to:

```
static int divisibleSumPairs(int n, int k, int[] ar) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if ((ar[i] + ar[j]) % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```